# How to run 1 .sh from DVD drive, and 2nd .sh from hard disk?

Tags: linux, bash, export

Environment: Linux RedHat 5 with bash terminal

I need to automate a process to do 2 things:

1. Have user install a dvd (with scripts) that prompt user for input,
   and create some directories on the hard drive.
2. Have a 2nd script scp some files to the hard drive directories, and
   then automatically burns a data dvd.

Right now I need the user to manually cd to the step 2 and run a .sh2.

General procedure:

1. User inputs provided disc, mounts the dvd drive,and is prompted for
   a "name".  Reading the variable "name", a directory and sub
   directories are created under /tmp/"name".
2. User must manually navigate to the /tmp/name dir and ./2.sh, to kick
   off the 2nd script.

I am having two issues with fully automating this using export name and kicking off the 2nd .sh.  The issue is the 2nd .sh requires the mounted dvd drive (that .sh1 is running from) to be ejected, and running .sh2 as & in the background completely skips over the scp data pull I am doing on .sh2.

So any ideas on how to export the .sh1 variable, eject the dvd with scripts, and then run the .sh2 script which can source the .sh1 (no longer running) script variable name?

I have considered writing a file with the variable name to the hard drive directory to solve the export variable issue (export name wasn't working), but I still haven't thought of how to make the .2sh automatically run from the /tmp/name dir (.sh2 & wasn't allowing scps/dvd burn to finish), perform the scp's, and allow my "burn dvd" .sh run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t provide enough details to work out all details of the answer. However:

1) If you want to unmount the DVD, neither the process invoking the first script, nor the first script itself (nor any other process) can have it as their current directory. This means, you cannot invoke the first script as `cd /media/dvd; bash ./1.sh`, but you have to do something like `bash /media/dvd/1.sh`

2) Just after creating `/tmp/name`, `cd` to it in the first script, create the second script, make it executable (don’t forget an appropriate shebang), and invoke it as `exec ./2.sh`. Using `exec` is crucial. If you don’t, the file of the first script stays open and the DVD mount point stays busy. If you use `exec`, the shell knows that no further line will be read from that file, closes it, and frees the DVD mount point.

3) The simplest way to pass a variable to a script is to pass it as a command line parameter. So you should invoke the second script with something like `exec ./2.sh "$name"` and refer to that parameter as `"$1"` in the text of the second script. However, if I understand correctly, what you want to pass is the same variable you have created the `/tmp/name` directory from, that is, the current directory of `./2.sh`. If this is the case, then its value can be retrieved by `name="$(basename $(pwd))` inside `2.sh`.

4) `export name` didn’t work for you because `export` makes a variable known to subprocesses of the current process, but the second script was not a subprocess of the first in your scenario. `export name` would work if you do as I have outlined in the above point, because when you `exec ./2.sh` the environment stays the same, but still, it is much more readable if you pass the value explicitly.

5) In general, when you plan to do stuff based on user input, it is **very** important to sanitize it before doing anything: check **any** user-provided string for emptyness, strange characters such as spaces, newlines, slashes, semicolons, etc... check also characters which might be harmless when operating on the filesystem, but might cause problems on the newly-burned DVD, check which characters are legal at every step of your procedure... In short, **don’t trust** user input.

Comment: Great answer Dario.  I just mounted the dvd_drive from the default bash login terminal, ran the 1_.sh from there "/media/dvd_drive/1.sh".  The "1.sh" scripts asked for the directory "name" to create.  I created it under "/tmp/name". The last line of the "1.sh" I called the 2nd scripts as "exec 2.sh".  In the beginning of the "2.sh" I cd'd to "/tmp/name" and entered "name="$(basename $(pwd))".  Great answer,

Comment: I am glad it worked. Please have a look [here to learn what to do when you are happy with somebody’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Voted (but I don't have enough reputation for it to show) and accepted.